# Closed form formula for a double series related to wave equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, special-functions

Does anyone have a closed form formula for the double series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m+1)^3(2n+1)^3}\cos\left(\pi t \sqrt{(2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2}\right)?$$
This is related to a solution of a two dimensional wave equation.

Comment: Could you say a few more words on the relation to wave equation? The series looks like a double integral computed by residues. If it indeed came like that, could you give the form of the integral?

Comment: Let $u(x,y,t)$ be the series solution of wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}, 0\lt x\lt 1, 0\lt y\lt 1, t\ge 0,$ $u(x,y,0)=(x-x^2)(y-y^2), u_t(x,y,0)=0$ and $ u(x,y,t)=0$ on the boundary of the square. Then the given double series is $u(1/2,1/2,t)$. If you could write that as an integral, that would be something.

Comment: Thank you, now I see. Above I meant very naive trick: write the sum as something like $$\int_C\int_C\frac{\cos\pi t \sqrt{p^2+q^2}\;dp\,dq}{p^3q^3\cos\frac{\pi p}{2}\cos\frac{\pi q}{2}}$$ where the contour $C$ circumvents the half-line of poles $1,3,5,\ldots$. But it doesn't seem to me that further deforming the contours one can get something computable.